# Aligning multiple smaller words with one bigger word?

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to code HTML and CSS, and I decided to make my own website in the process.

My question is: how would I align smaller text to a bigger object, for example, links to different pages on my website neatly aligned under my full name with the links flush to the of the beginning and end of my full name?

I know describing it may have been a bit confusing, so here's an image of what I mean:

[image: Sample image]

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yeah I have tried declaring fixed margins for each word, which almost works — they're not totally aligned at each end of the bigger word. I also tried setting a width which yielded the same result. Am I using the wrong methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> links flush to the beginning and end of my full name

Get out of the habit of thinking this way as you design websites. This will lead to endless headaches and frustrations for you, as it depends on browser rendering (and possibly rendering bugs), the user's font size, the user's font, and loads of other factors you cannot control. Instead of going for 'pixel precision', the idea is simply to make it look as good as you can on most things.

When designing things like this, **consider the markup first**. What is the structure of what you're actually writing? In your linked image, `Full Name` looks to me like a header (perhaps `h1`), while menus like that are normally done as styled unordered lists (`ul`) these days. Below is an example of how I might make something similar to what is in your image.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Full Name</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>music</li>
        <li>film</li>
        <li>web</li>
        <li>photo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS used, with comments:

```
#container { border: 1px solid; }
h1 { 
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center; 
}
ul { 
    margin: 0.5em;
    /* remove default padding inserted by browser */
    padding-left: 0;
    /* no bullets */
    list-style-type: none;
    /* this works on inline objects, not just text */
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    /* hybrid of inline and block; obeys text-align */
    /* Also note this does not work in IE <9. Workarounds exist. */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

And here is the end result: http://jsfiddle.net/3PLgz/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't down vote you, though. I can't do that until I have 15 reputation, apparently — not that I would, though! I tried up-voting you and it didn't work.

Comment: Not to worry. Someone downvoted my answer because it shows -1, and I'd like to know why so I can possibly improve it. Oh, well. Hope I helped. [edit: PS, if you think it is correct or you are going to use it, you can indicate as much by clicking the check box to accept it as the right answer]

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the look and design regardless of the header length, but in the end, CSS doesn't offer as precise typographical tools as you'd need and you will have to nudge the percentages one way or another once you know the length of your actual text.

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ427/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Large Title Here Etc</h1>
    <div id="sub">
        <span>music</span>
        <span>film</span>
        <span>web</span>
        <span>photo</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#sub {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: table;
    width: 120%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 -10%;
}

#sub span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 2%;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, note here that I had to resize the JSFiddle window to see it. On first click, the header wrapped and the effect was lost. (Still looked good, though.) Just remember when you're designing websites that just because you see it that way, I guarantee you everyone else will not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I wasn't suggesting that you change your fiddle. I both complimented and upvoted your answer.